# Entity Framework, create superuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to create superuser in my ASP.NET MVC application. I read that I can achieve it by adding `"admin"` role and check by filters is a current user has this role.

I read in tutorials how to create users and roles when app start, but in all tutorials they don't use entity framework. So I tried to create superuser in `Configuration.cs` file in the `Migration` folder:

```
namespace WebApp.Migrations
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApp.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(WebApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
            var admin = new ApplicationUser { Email = "mail@growapps.ru", UserName = "Growapps" };
            string password = "mail123";

            var result = userManager.Create(admin, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, "admin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after I add-migrations and update-database new user doesn't appear. Am I understand right, that Seed method calls after each migration and should create a new user? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If not, how else can I add super user when my web app first start?

Comment: You need to check like if(userAlreadyexists) return; I didn't find any wrong here.. Have you got any error? I guess your admin obejct didn't have required all fields (FirstName, LastName). Please check this http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/  at Step7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake was not obvious, in "log in" view of template (that is generated by ASP.NET MVC) u should type "email" and password, the problem is that Login method in controller sends that email field as user name, so if u create user in code with different values of name and email u will have difficulty to log in. I guess microsoft should change placeholder name of field in their template :D